# Difference between array difference

Tags: c

I am trying to pass a 2D array to a function. I tried different solution provided on the internet.

```
int arr[3][4];
fun (arr);



1) void fun(int *a[4]) {} -- result into a compilation error (cannot convert int (*)[4] to int **)

2) void fun(int(*a)[4]) {} -- works fine.
```

I want to know what is the difference between two above declaration and what there is a error in 1. case.

Comment: Please edit your code, this is neither C nor C++!

Comment: `int arr[3][4]` will degenerate into `int*`, not `int**`!

Comment: One of these takes an array of `int` pointers (the size is lost during the decay), the other takes a pointer to an `int` array of four values. They're entirely different beasts.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: No, it will decay into `int(*)[4]`, not `int*`.

Answer (score 5):

Well, here's what the ever-helpful [cdecl](http://www.cdecl.org/) says about it:

- `int *a[4]` means "declare a as array 4 of pointer to int"
- `int(*a)[4]` means "declare a as pointer to array 4 of int"

Comment: But in a function parameter declaration, `int *a[4]` means declare `a` as pointer to pointer to `int`. This is important in the context of the question.

Answer (score 1):

This declares an **array of 4 pointers to integers**:

```
int* a[4];     // (a)
```

This, on the other hand:

```
int (*a)[4];   // (b)
```

Declares a **pointer to an array of 4 integers**.

Since arrays decay to pointers (to their first element) when used as function arguments, passing an object of type `int arr[3][4]` to a function which accepts a parameter of type *(b)* above will succeed (decaying to a pointer to `int[4]`, i.e an `int (*)[4])`, while it will fail when the parameter type is *(a)*.

Answer (score 0):

1. `int* a[4]` is an array of 4 `int*`s
2. `int (*a)[4]` is a pointer to an array of 4 `int`s

The name of an array can be converted to a pointer to its first element. That is `arr`, since it is the name of an `int[3][4]`, will be converted to a pointer to the first element of `arr` which is itself an `int[4]`. That type is a `int(*)[4]`. That's why you can pass `arr` in the second case.

In C++, you can pass a reference to the full array like so:

```
void fun(int(&a)[3][4]) {}
```

In this case, no array-to-pointer conversion occurs. You are simply taking a reference to the 2D array itself.

Answer (score 0):

`int *a[4]` is an array of 4 pointers to `int`, whereas `int(*a)[4]` is a pointer to an array of 4 `int`.

Since an array decays to a pointer to its first element (as long as it is not used as an operand of `&`, `sizeof` or `_Alignof`), `a[3][4]` will be converted to `(*a)[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

In the function call

```
fun(arr);
```

the type of the *expression* `arr` is "3-element array of 4-element array of `int`".  Since `arr` is not an operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, it will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to 4-element array of `int`", which is written as `int (*arr)[4]`, and its value will be the address of `a[0]`.

Postfix operators like `[]` and `()` have a higher precedence than unary operators like `*`, so `*a[N]` is an `N`-element array of pointers, whereas `(*a)[N]` is a pointer to an `N`-element array.  Similarly, `*f()` is a function returning a pointer, while `(*f)()` is a pointer to a function.